# Convert shapefile to DWG with FME keeping all the attributes from shapefile

Tags: shapefile, convert, fme-form

I have a shapefile that I want to convert to a DWG file. I want to be able to see all the information (of attribute table) shapefile to the layer properties on AutoCAD. I have tried many things but nothing worked.

[image: This is the attribute table of my shp file]

Comment: You will need to use the Extended Entity Data on the 
 DWG Writer https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q000080hQGISA2/shape-to-autocad-with-attributes?childToView=23480

Comment: I have tried this but didn't work

Comment: Can you share/screenshot your FME workbench flow?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/103rkm0 i have also check at the beginning the extended entity data on the dwg writer

Comment: Can you see the Extended Entity Data if you read the file back into FME? I'd guess not, but it would certainly be the first thing I'd check.

Comment: That is very intersting... I did that you said Mark Ireland and i can see the attribute table on the FME.  https://prnt.sc/1049yig 
I am very confused.